# Recuperar dados para o Controller em Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.3

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web com Laravel e em uma das minhas telas tenho uma relação Cliente e Contato, onde um cliente pode ter vários contatos.

então na minha View eu tenho um método para ir adicionando meus contato a uma table. por exemplo: informo os campos celular, telefone e email e clico em adicionar contato e ele vai salvando ...

a minha dúvida é, como posso enviar esses dados para o meu controller cliente?

[EDIT]

Tenho uma tela create-edit Cliente. onde tenho os dados do cliente: Nome, Cpf, Email ... e então tenho 3 campos celular, telefone e email e um botão adicionar, onde vou informando esses 3 campos e adicionando na tabela. meu problema é na hora de enviar as informações dessa tabela para o servidor.

Comment: Do Front-End para o Back-End em Laravel? 
Da uma olhada nisso https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27346205/submit-form-laravel-using-ajax
Nesse exemplo ele está enviando um novo comentário para ser adicionado pelo controlador usando o método add que ele criou

Comment: Eu só conseguiria enviar isso via ajax? não consigo enviar os dados via form? com todo o cadastro do cliente de uma só vez

Comment: Form você teria que atualizar sua página e a table seria perdida, vai por mim, usa ajax e atualiza a tabela usando o Jquery é mais robusto e fácil de dar manutenção. (Se quiser usar o Javascript puro, sem Jquery e Ajax, também é um boa)

Comment: O ajax você também pode submeter o form inteiro

Comment: Entendi, mas no caso teria que ser pelo form mesmo :/ pois assim que eu envia-se esses dados da teria que dar um redirect e mudar a route

Comment: nesse caso é só usar 
action="<?=$host?>+'controlador/metodo'" no form

Comment: Eu já tenho um form, e já estou enviando as informações ... o problema é que os dados da table não vai ... {!! Form::open(['route' => 'clientes.store', 'class'=>'form']) !!}

Comment: Table não carrega dados de form, somente input

Comment: E qual o melhor método para passar os dados de uma table para o controller?

Comment: Dependendo do Plugin de construção da table, o jquery pode recuperar o objeto com os dados e você envia por ajax, verifica se deu sucesso, se sim, você chama outro método para alterar a rota

Comment: Os comentários só deixaram a questão mais confusa, você tem uma tabela onde lista clientes e esses clientes vão ter cadastros de contatos na mesma página onde os clientes ficam listados certo? Se possivel poderia mostrar como sua tabelas está para termos uma noção do que foi feito?

Comment: Vou tentar atualizar minha pergunta com relação a esse comentário que você fez.